# Google Dart requestAnimationFrame doesnt accept callback

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:html';

main() {
    new test();
}

class test {
  test() {
    print(x);
  }

  void x() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(x);
  }
}
```

I could use animationFrame but I want more control so I try to use requestAnimationFrame (without futures). So I call the method from my window object and pass in the callback only to get the following error message:

```
The argument type '() → void' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'FrameRequestCallback(num) → void'.
```

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/fb763a4a770b5cdd896982e10ccf4118

According to dart my x variable is a closure of instance test, great. It cant be void then.

The documentation clearly states the function accepts a callback of type FrameRequestCallback  (the method I assume). The function then returns an integer / num. Why doesnt my test project work?

Comment: The Dartpad doesn't use `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer oh my god. I didnt know that. So I was doing everything right? It does use animationFrame though

Comment: Your Dartpad uses https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.1/dart-html/Window-class.html `window.animationFrame.then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.1/dart-html/FrameRequestCallback.html shows that a param of type `num` is expected.

This should work then

```
  void x(num value) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(x);
  }
```

Comment: Probably the timestamp

Comment: Thing is, I thought it was optional :D oops.

Comment: `typedef void FrameRequestCallback([num highResTime]);` would be optional but it actually doesn't have the `[]` ;-)

Comment: Oh, just read that Dart supports real threads in form of isolates, nice.

Comment: But isolates are currently quite limited in the browser, because they don't allow access to the browser API which limits it to pure calculations (no HTTP request, not DOM access, no LocalStorage, ...) It was mentioned that this is because of Dartium. When DDC becomes officially available they will tackle the isolates limitation in the browser.

Comment: As far as im concerned web workers cant access the dom anyways.

Comment: Right, but web workers can fetch data from the server, process it and than allow to fetch it from the main isolate. With Dart isolates, you currently need to fetch the data in the UI thread and then pass it to the isolate. If it still works for your use case it's fine of course. I just want to make you aware that there are severe limitations one might not expect.

Comment: You are really right. I cant wait till they release DDC :D. Saw a demonstration of it, really cool.

Comment: This happens sometimes online. I'm surprised myself every time, because at home I'm usually not ;-) Yes, DDC should be a big step forward.

Comment: Just saw this mentioned https://github.com/filiph/prime_finder in https://gitter.im/dart-lang/dev_compiler, might be interesting as isolate example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133631/discussion-between-asperger-and-gunter-zochbauer).